# How to align <img> and <p> tags at the bottom?

Tags: css

there, I am creating something like the screenshot below for a person's introduction. But at the bottom I would like to align the image and the paragraph at the bottom, so I would have the text wrap around the image like the second image. Is that possible in CSS?

```
<div class="ppl-detail">
     <img class="ppl-proj" src="images/who/pure-systems.png">
     <p class="ppl-text">Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.</p>
</div>
```

Thank you![image] [image]

Comment: Could you post your css?

Comment: with your code layout you wouldn't be able to achieve this with pure css - the only way would be to put your image halfway down he text and float it left

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "float: left" in css.

```
img {
   float:left;
   border:1px dotted black;
   margin:0px 0px 15px 20px;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/26WZe/

Comment: Though to have the effect as it is in the second image, the commenter (Pete) above is right - the image tag will have to exist in the middle of the text. EDIT: you did it in the fiddle cheers

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with CSS alone unless you're going to put the image in the middle of the text like @ashis-kumar's answer. I wrote some javascript (no third party library required, but could easily be rewritten to work with jQuery):

```js
var util = {
    iterations: 0,
    fontSize: 20,
    wrapWords: function(el) {
        var words = el.textContent.split(' ');
        for ( var i = 0, l = words.length; i < l; ++i ) {
            words[i] = '<span class="word">' + words[i] + ' </span>';
        }
        el.innerHTML = words.join('');
        return document.querySelectorAll('span.word');
    },
    checkOffsets: function(words, img, newContainer, origContainer) {
        var top = img.offsetTop;
        for ( var i = 0, l = words.length; i < l; ++i ) {
            origContainer.appendChild(words[i]);
        }
        origContainer.appendChild(newContainer);
        for ( i = 0, l = words.length; i < l; ++i ) {
            var word = words[i];
            if ( word.offsetTop + word.offsetHeight >= top ) {
                newContainer.appendChild(word);
            }
        }
        if ( Math.abs(img.offsetTop - newContainer.offsetTop) > this.fontSize || img.offsetTop < newContainer.offsetTop ) {
            this.iterations++;
            if ( this.iterations < 10 ) {
                this.checkOffsets(words, img, newContainer, origContainer);
            }

        }
    }
};

var img = document.querySelector('img');
var p = document.querySelector('p');
var words = util.wrapWords(p);
var pushContainer = document.createElement('div');
pushContainer.classList.add('push');
p.appendChild(pushContainer);


util.checkOffsets(words, img, pushContainer, p);
```

### [See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/yrWEw/3/)

I wrote it pretty quickly, but what it basically does is wraps all the words in the paragraph with a `<span>` so that finding its offset is easier. Then it creates another element for all the words that will be next to the image. It then goes through them until it finds the correct number of words to go into it (it is recursive in case there's too much space or not enough). There are probably some optimizations that can be done, but it's pretty quick.

Answer (score 0):

Add a "float" selector to your image:

```
<img class="ppl-proj" src="images/who/pure-systems.png" style="float:left; padding-right:10px;">
```

That will get you started. You might need to tweak it a bit, but if you lookup how to use floats, you'll figure it out.

Here is a good learning resource:

http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/

Answer (score -1):

I did it this way: `<input type='button' style='position:fixed' top:94%; left:82%; width:100px' value='` 
you can position this way `<div>`, `<p>` and so on.