# HTML/CSS: How to put a image in the bottom right corner and wrap text around it?

Tags: html, css

`float:right` and `position:fixed` doesn't work, because it's not possible to wrap text around that. Any suggestions, using HTML/CSS and maybe even Javascript, are more than welcome!

Comment: Hm... I've tried to get that to work too once, but I haven't managed to do it. Why can you float something in the top left or top right corner of a container, but not in the bottom left of bottom right ones? So, good question. However, you should really provide some examples of what you've tried. Give the people here a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to play with; they like that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to align <img> and <p> tags at the bottom?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18020222/how-to-align-img-and-p-tags-at-the-bottom)

Answer (score 0):

The best would be `float:center` but unfortunately this doesn't exist. Here is a work around which might give you the result you want to achieve: http://css-tricks.com/float-center/ .